# Select all Forms in a div and prevent the default action

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to Display part of my website in a layover. If the user has no javascript, the layover is displayed as a normal website.

I'm getting the Website with `getController` and my problem occures in `handleLinksAndForm`.

```
$("#Popup > a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        getController($(this).attr("href").substr(1),element);
    });
```

This works as intended. Whenever a click on a Anchor element in Popover div happens, the default action is prevented and the new website is loaded in the popover.

```
$("#Popup > form").each(function() {
               alert(this.name);
});
$("#Popup > form").submit(function(e) {
            alert("form");
            e.preventDefault();
            getPostController($(this).attr("action"),$(this).serialize(),element);
            return false;
});
```

However, this part does not work. Neither the foreach part nor the .submit().

So my Question is: Whats my mistake? If I use `$("form").each(function() {...` all forms are recognized, but if I add the extra selector #Popup none is recognized.

Complete Code:

```
function getController(ctrl,element)
{
    $.get('/service/controller/' + ctrl, function(data){
        handleLinksAndForm(data,element)        
    })
}
function getPostController(ctrl,args,element)
{
    $.post('/service/controller/' + ctrl,args, function(data) {
        handleLinksAndForm(data,element)        
    });
}

function handleLinksAndForm(data,element)
{
    element.html(data);
    element.prepend("<div id=\"popupClose\">x</a>");
    centerPopup();
    $("#popupClose").click(function(){
        disablePopup();
   });
    $("#Popup > a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        getController($(this).attr("href").substr(1),element);
    });
    $("#Popup > form").each(function() {
           alert(this.name);
        });
    $("#Popup > form").submit(function(e) {
        alert("form");
        e.preventDefault();
        getPostController($(this).attr("action"),$(this).serialize(),element);
        return false;
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure targeted forms are direct children of #Popup? What about posting relevant HTML?

Comment: can you post some raw html also to make more clearer picture, it seems you are preventing the default action on child element which fails to trigger at parent action i.e. form. and don't use `preventDefault()` and `return false` togeather.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but I found my error and it was HTML related. Check my own answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provided any html code. So hard to say if isn't here more problems for example if is really element form a child of #popup.
But first try to use:

```
return false;
```

instead:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Also you can use:
$("#Popup form") instead $("#Popup > form") it is safer way.

Comment: Thanks for that. I will use that.

Comment: `return false` actually calls `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` which will result in making the future anchor tags to behave surprisingly if we did'nt use correct selectors. If only cancling the default behaviour of action, you should always prefer `preventDefault()` and it makes sense too.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested with the code below and I was able to locate the child element.

```
$("form", "#Popup").submit(function(e) {
  alert("form");
  ...
});
```

N.B. This syntax also calls .find() but is slightly easier on the eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Found my mistake:

I got:

```
<table>
<form>
   <tr><td>...</td></tr>
</form>
</table>
```

The right way is:

```
<form>
<table>
    ...
</table>
</form>
```